# Plotly: How to create a barchart using group by?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have a dataset as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = dict(Pclass=[1,1,2,2,3,3],
            Survived = [0,1,0,1,0,1],
            CategorySize = [80,136,97,87,372,119] )
```

I need to create a `barchart` using `plotly` in **python**, which is grouped by **Pclass**. in each group, i have 2 columns for `Survived=0` and `Survived=1` and in Y axis i should have the `CategorySize`. Therefore, i must have 6 bars which are in 3 groups.

Here is what i have tried:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [ go.Bar( x = PclassSurvived.Pclass, y = PclassSurvived.CategorySize ) ]
layout = go.Layout(title= 'Pclass-Survived', xaxis = dict(title = 'Pclass'), yaxis = dict(title = 'CategorySize'),barmode='group' )
fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)

pyo.plot( fig, filename='./Output/Pclass-Survived.html')
```

But, it is not what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble with your sample dataset. `PclassSurvived.Pclass` and `PclassSurvived.CategorySize` are not defined, and it's not 100% clear to me what you would like to accomplish here. But judging by your explanations and the structure of your dataset, it seems that this could get you somewhere:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = dict(Pclass=[1,1,2,2,3,3],
            Survived = [0,1,0,1,0,1],
            CategorySize = [80,136,97,87,372,119] )
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

s0=df.query('Survived==0')
s1=df.query('Survived==1')

#layout = go.Layout(title= 'Pclass-Survived', xaxis = dict(title = 'Pclass'), yaxis = dict(title = 'CategorySize'),barmode='group' )
fig = go.Figure()

data=data['Pclass']

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=s0['Pclass'], y = s0['CategorySize'],
                    name='dead'
                    )
             )

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=s1['Pclass'], y = s1['CategorySize'],
                    name='alive'
                    )
             )

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

---

**Edit:** You can produce the same plot using the `plotly.offline` module like this:

**Code 2:**

```
# Import the necessaries libraries
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# Set notebook mode to work in offline
pyo.init_notebook_mode()

# data
data = dict(Pclass=[1,1,2,2,3,3],
            Survived = [0,1,0,1,0,1],
            CategorySize = [80,136,97,87,372,119] )
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

# 
s0=df.query('Survived==0')
s1=df.query('Survived==1')

fig = go.Figure()

data=data['Pclass']

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=s0['Pclass'], y = s0['CategorySize'],
                    name='dead'
                    )
             )

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=s1['Pclass'], y = s1['CategorySize'],
                    name='alive'
                    )
             )

pyo.iplot(fig, filename = 'your-library')
```

**Alternative approach with stacked bars:**

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 3:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = dict(Pclass=[1,1,2,2,3,3],
            Survived = [0,1,0,1,0,1],
            CategorySize = [80,136,97,87,372,119] )
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

s0=df.query('Survived==0')
s1=df.query('Survived==1')

#layout = go.Layout(title= 'Pclass-Survived', xaxis = dict(title = 'Pclass'), yaxis = dict(title = 'CategorySize'),barmode='group' )
fig = go.Figure()

data=data['Pclass']

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=s0['Pclass'], y = s0['CategorySize'],
                    name='dead'
                    )
             )

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=s1['Pclass'], y = s1['CategorySize'],
                    name='alive'
                    )
             )

df_tot = df.groupby('Pclass').sum()

annot1 = [dict(
            x=xi,
            y=yi,
            text=str(yi),
            xanchor='auto',
            yanchor='bottom',
            showarrow=False,
        ) for xi, yi in zip(df_tot.index, df_tot['CategorySize'])]

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', annotations=annot1)
fig.show()
```

Comment: thanks. unfortunately i cannot accept your answer, since you did not used my library.
i gave you an upvote.

Comment: @Jeff Is one of the charts what you needed?

Comment: The first one is what i needed. i used the idea for filtering. so, at the end the key was in filtering data.

Comment: @Jeff What do you mean by 'your library' by the way? plotly.offline?

Answer (score 5):

This could be easily done with `Pandas`'s `groupby` and [Plotly Express.](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/)

You should group your data by `Pclass` and `Survived` columns, and apply the *sum* aggregate function to the `CategorySize` column.

This way you'll get 6 groups, with their aggregate values, and you can easily plot for each group a pair of bar charts (side-byside) thanks to the `barmode` attribute (by using the `'group'` value), you can read more about it in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html).

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        Pclass=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        Survived=[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        CategorySize=[80, 136, 97, 87, 372, 119],
    )
)
```

Now you group the data:

```py
grouped_df = data.groupby(by=["Pclass", "Survived"], as_index=False).agg(
    {"CategorySize": "sum"}
)
```

And convert the `Survived` column values to strings (so plotly treat it as a discrete variable, rather than numeric variable):

```py
grouped_df.Survived = grouped_df.Survived.map({0: "Died", 1: "Survived",})
```

Now, you should have:

|  | Pclass | Survived | CategorySize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Died | 80 |
| 1 | 1 | Survived | 136 |
| 2 | 2 | Died | 97 |
| 3 | 2 | Survived | 87 |
| 4 | 3 | Died | 372 |
| 5 | 3 | Survived | 119 |

Finally, you visualize your data:

```py
fig = px.bar(
    data_frame=grouped_df,
    x="Pclass",
    y="CategorySize",
    color="Survived",
    barmode="group",
)

fig.show()
```

[image]